# why set(array) is faster than array.sort()

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, set

I was solving a hackerrank challenge.(in Python 3)
At one point I needed to sort a list and work with it.
(2 <= len(array) <= 10^5)
The list is containing **unique** integers.
I used `arr.sort()`, but I was getting "Time limit exceeded" message
Then I found if I use `set(arr)`, it runs fast and passes all test cases.
here's is my function for more clarification

```
def pairs(k, ar):
  ar.sort()
  c=0
  for i in ar:
    if i+k in ar:
      c+=1
  return c
```

This gets me "Time limit exceeded"

```
def pairs(k, ar):
  ar=set(ar)
  c=0
  for i in ar:
    if i+k in ar:
      c+=1
  return c
```

This one with set() runs faster.
Why is this set() is faster than sort().
Don't they use same sorting algorithm?

Comment: Because the one with set is linear time, the one without it is quadratic

Comment: Until Python 3.6, sets were not sorted.  Since then, they are.

Comment: @TimRoberts `set` objects are absolutely not sorted in Python, not even as an implementation detail in any of the major implementations

Comment: "Why is this set() is faster than sort(). " It's not either of these calls that is fast or slow here; it's *the `in` operator*. `set` doesn't use a sorting algorithm at all, and produces something completely different. That said, the reason that sorting the list gives you a much slower result than using a set is that *sorting the list doesn't help `in` work at all*; the `in` operator has no way to know that the list has been sorted, and therefore every element is still checked every time.

Comment: @Loocid I'm new in python and I used set so many times to get sorted items and it worked.  Also `set([54, 23]) = {23,54}` here in my ide

Comment: @TimRoberts are you perhaps thinking of dicts (which *preserve their insertion order* - not the same thing)?

Comment: "Don't they use same sorting algorithm?" set objects don't use any sorting algorithm at all

Comment: @RifatBhuiyan yeah, that's completely incorrect. What you are seeing is an artifact of the fact that `int` objects (mostly) hash to themselves

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yea and important to not `set` objects dont' maintain insertion order

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Note that a presorted `list` *could* gain some speed on containment checks (going from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`) by using the `bisect` module functions. But sorting (`O(n log n)`) plus repeated binary search (`O(log n)`) is almost certainly going to be much slower than conversion to `set` (`O(n)`) plus repeated `set` lookup (average case `O(1)`). But yeah, `in` on a sorted `list` and `in` on an unsorted `list` have identical performance (only way they'd differ in practice is if the thing being searched for was likely to be bigger or smaller than most elements of the `list`).

Comment: @RifatBhuiyan: `==` on `set`s compares them w/o regard to iteration order, so that would be true even if the `set`s in question had the same values but iterated in different orders. Try it with `{-2, -1}` and `{-1, -2}`. They iterate in different orders (because I chose two values that, as an implementation detail of CPython, have identical hashes, so the first seen occupies its desired bucket, while the second hops around to find an open one; other values do this too, they're just a little harder to find), but they're still equal to each other. `set` doesn't sort, and has no useful ordering.